# Rails 4, Instance variable in custom action not updating, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, instance-variables

In this quiz I'm building when an answer is clicked, I want the @taken instance variable to change from "No" to "Yes"

Here i assign it to "No" if nil in my show action

```
def show
    if @taken == nil
        @taken = "No"
    end
end
```

Then here I update it to "Yes" if the submit_answer action is called.  Thing is the flash notices are working correctly when an answer is clicked so I know that this action is working.  But for some reason it doesn't update the @taken variable.  Why?

controller#action

```
def submit_answer
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])

    if @answer.correct_answer == true
        flash[:notice] = "You did it!"
        @taken = "Yes"
        redirect_to :back

    else
        flash[:notice] =  "Sorry wrong answer!"
        @taken = "Yes"
        redirect_to :back   
    end
end
```

view.html.haml

```
- @question.answers.each do |answer|
            .sub-panel.top-padding.green-hover
                - if @taken == "No"
                    %li.padding-left= link_to "#{answer.content}", submit_answer_path(answer_id: answer.id)
                - else 
                    %li.padding-left= answer.content

= @taken.inspect
```

routes.rb

```
get 'quizzes/answer/:answer_id', to: 'quizzes#submit_answer', as: :submit_answer
```

What's happening is it's setting @taken to "No" correctly in the show action. But then after the submit_answer action is called and the flash notice displays, it doesn't update the @taken instance variable to yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails controller you will not get instance variable(`@variable`) of one action in another action. For this you have to create class variable (`@@variable`).

For more you can go through this [link](http://www.glennfu.com/2008/02/20/persistent-instance-variables-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure class variable is the wrong way to go.

Comment: Yes you are right but in scenario it's necessary. There are other ways also like maintaining things using form variable and attribute accessors. But I have answered as per question.

Answer (score 2):

Controller instance variables are not remembered between requests.